# How do i protect my self from "Form grabbing" attack?

Tags: keyloggers, sandbox

I'm writing a simple piece of security software - I'm interested in attack techniques and especially in how to protect my users from this attack?

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_grabbing) I can see how its works: it hooks the API call of the browser before sending data.

It's a dangerous attack, even advanced-Keylogger-obfuscation techniques don't work in this way.

I have some knowledge about hooking and sandboxing applications, but I'm not sure..if I sandbox/virtualize all API calls from the browser can this protect my users?

**UPDATE**: Shame, there is no person understands the question?

Comment: Can you explain what your software is for? You say it is 'security software' but this could mean anything.

Comment: Yes, is something like anti-KL...

Comment: What does anti-kl mean? Best not to assume that acronyms are known by everyone.

Comment: it's Anti-KeyLogger

Comment: To Downvoter: I'm curious, and i want to know if i make something wrong..? :3

Comment: It's an unwinnable battle.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Please explain more about your remark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form grabbing attacks happens when a malicious script/program captures your form with your private information.  The most straightforward way to do this is with javascript extension.

The best prevention is to:

1. use your own trusted computer (malware that could capture form data),
2. install your OS/programs from trusted source,
3. do not install browser extensions/user scripts (especially from untrusted sources) or at the very least use private browsing (with all extensions disabled) when you go to these sites,
4. use a modern up-to-date browser,
5. only use passwords over https connections (this makes it more difficult for attackers to insert javascript in cross-site scripting),
6. Also consider disabling javascript.

---

EDIT:

My original answer mostly was concerned with your title `How do i protect myself from "Form grabbing" attack?` versus instructing you on how to write security software.  Otherwise I agree with [CodesInChaos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31368/how-do-i-protect-my-self-from-form-grabbing-attack/31409#comment48582_31368) remark: "It's an unwinnable battle".

There are two distinct places form-grabbing could occur: either from the browser (e.g., an XSS attack loading malicious JS, or a malicious extension installed in the browser) OR monitoring API calls via [hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking).

There are a variety of ways of hooking, but if a user/malware has sufficient privileges to insert API hooks, they probably also have enough power to make the output of your hooking detection tests untrustable.

For example, if someone was mounting [this style of attack to log all http/https requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking#API.2FFunction_Hooking.2FInterception_Using_JMP_Instruction) you could detect try to detect if the shared library (aka DLL) has changed (granted every benign upgrade to that library will trigger false positives) or contains a certain malware signature.

Now let's say the altered shared library is saved to disk in its altered form.  Now your anti-hooking program computes a cryptographic hashsum to check that the library has not been altered to compare against the known function of the unmodified library.  But what prevents the attacker from just hooking into those calls to calculate the checksum and altering the output to be the pre-modified checksum whenever the malicious checksum comes up?  Nothing, unless of course you are analyzing a hard disk from a safe operating system (e.g., mounted the drive read-only from another computer not infected with the malware).

Granted, due to threats of runtime modification of libraries, you really need to check the instructions in the memory of the process that is running versus the static files.  In this sort of situation, you really need to have the potential malware running to capture the API-hooking attack, though all your safe utilities cannot be trusted as the system has already been compromised.  (You could still scan the disk from a safe setup for whatever program is eventually altering the memory to insert the API-hooks, but its a much harder task where you only find the types of attacks you know to look for).

Comment: I'm talking about API hooking, what about: http://www.rohitab.com/api-monitor-tutorial-sniffing-firefox-ssl-traffic  ?

Comment: Also, i'm not looking how to protect my self,rather  i'm making an anti-keylloger and looking how to protect browsers from API Hooking..

Comment: @SmartyTwiti = updated answer significantly.